# VB.net 2013 Display Database Record According Listbox Selection

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, listbox

I want to display Database Record into textbox according to my listbox selection.

I have showed database record by NAME into listbox like this.

```
Private Sub getPurchases()
    cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM detail_buy ORDER BY id DESC", conn)
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    LBPmb.DataSource = dt
    LBPmb.ValueMember = "name"
End Sub
```

Now I want to show the other value like ID, Price, Total, etc,etc into each textboxes when I click the 'names' on listbox. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the same `DataTable` to the `TextBoxes` as well, e.g.

```
With myListBox
    .DisplayMember = "ColumnToDisplay1"
    .ValueMember = "PKColumn"
    .DataSource = myDataTable
End With

myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataTable, "ColumnToDisplay2")
```

The `TextBox` will then be automatically populated when you make a selection in the `ListBox`.